# NSUserDefaults automatically called on adding observer NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsnotificationcenter

I have added a notification observer in my code to get to know if there is any change in the `NSUserDefaults` but my method automatically being called with been use of `NSUserDefaults`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsSettingsChanged:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

my method `defaultsSettingsChanged` get called automatically only in iPad 3 , iPad mini this works fine and does not called automatically. Even though I remove all the `NSUserdefaults`methods `defaultsSettingsChanged` calls once